# Spark SQL Union on Empty dataframe

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

We have glue job running script in which we have created two dataframes using createOrReplaceTempView command. The dataframes are then joined via a union:

```
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")

joined_df = spark.sql(
"""
Select 
  id
, name
, product
, year
, month
, day

from df1

Union ALL

Select 
  id
, name
, product
, year
, month
, day

from df2

"""
)

joined_df.createOrReplaceTempView("joined_df")
```

Everything appeared to be working fine until it failed. Upon research, I am speculating it is because one of the dataframe is empty. This job runs daily and occasionally, one of the dataframe will not have data for the day (df2).

The error message returned in Cloudwatch log is not entirely clear:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '`id`' given input columns: 
[]; line 22 pos 7;\n'Union\n:- Project [contract_id#0, agr_type_cd#1, ind_product_cd#2, 
report_dt#3, effective_dt#4, agr_trns_cd#5, agreement_cnt#6, dth_bnft#7, admn_system_cd#8, 
ind_lob_cd#9, cca_agreement_cd#10, year#11, month#12, day#13]\n:  +- SubqueryAlias `df1`\n
'Project ['id, name#20,
 'product, 'year, 'month, 'day]\n   +- SubqueryAlias `df2`\n      +- LogicalRDD false\n"
```

I'm seeking advice on how to resolve such an issue. Thank you.

UPDATE:
I'm fairly certain I know the issue, but unsure on how to solution. On days where the source file in s3 is "empty" no records but only has the header row, the read from catalog returns an empty set:

```
df2 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
       database = glue_database,
       table_name = df2_table,
       push_down_predicate = pred
       )
df2 = df2.toDF()
df2.show()

The output: 
++
||
++
++
```

Essentially, the from_catalog method is not reading the schema from Glue. I would expect that even without data, the header would be detected and a union would just return everything from df1. But, since I'm receiving a empty set without header, the union cannot occur because it's acting as though the "schema has changed" or non-existent... But, the underlying s3 files have not changed schema. This job triggers daily when source files have been loaded to S3. When there is data in the file, the union does not fail as the schema can be detected from_catalog. Is there a way to read the header even when no data returns?

Comment: Seems like the the schema of your DataFrames changed or you're loading the wrong data. The problem is not with the `union` but selecting the columns from your DataFrames.

Comment: @danielsepulvedab Is there a way to detect which dataframe the error is occurring on? I'm wondering if the empty dataframe has "empty spaces" as it's just a file loaded with the header when it's empty.

Comment: You have to check the sources and find out why they changed the structure. I guess you have to somewhere in your code something like `df1 = spark.read.json("path/to/source")` and the same for `df2`. Check those paths and whatever write the files there. The schema of those files changed, that's what you have to fix.

Comment: @danielsepulvedab You're absolutely correct that it is not the union. I found that when the s3 file is empty (only header), from_catalog method is returning an empty set / empty table. Which causes the union to fail. Is there a way to force a read of the schema from catalog even in the event that source s3 file is empty (it does have a header row though). I have updated the post.